# Product_ID in my Invoice table

Tags: mysql, table

I'm doing a uni assignment.

I have

- a stock table where stock is assigned an ID (product_ID).
- a sales table where the stock is purchased.
- an invoice table where sales are processed.

I want the invoice entry to contain many product_id's and their quantities.

I currently have "Invoice_id, Customer_id, Staff_id, Product_id, Quantity, Price, Total Cost".

Doing it this way I can only have one product_id per entry. I want there to be multiple entries under one invoice_ID.

Am I thinking of this the right way? When you get an invoice it says the product on it and how many of them you bought.

Comment: *"Doing it this way i can only have one product_id per entry..."* *This way* isn't clear. You've just listed column names. Post the SQL `create table` statements instead so we don't have to guess. [See SHOW CREATE TABLE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html)

Comment: Where would i find those statements? all the tables are created currently.

Im not sure how i can explain which way ive done it. I have 7 or 8 different tables, suppliers, staff, customers, stock, sales, orders, invoices, requests.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>` is a SQL statement in MySQL (but not necessarily in other SQL dialects). Run it just like you ran your `CREATE TABLE ...` statements.

Comment: https://app.photobucket.com/u/Christopherspainter/p/37695c1e-3957-46f4-8a69-152046adb8e2

Can you see that?

Comment: Edit your question, and paste the three create table statements into it.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter - take a look at [mcve] to see how to ask a great question here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you're trying to accomplish, you'll want to normalize your data into two Invoice related tables. One for header information, e.g. Invoice_Id, Invoice_Date, Customer_Id, TotalCost; and one for the invoice line information, e.g. InvoiceLine_Id, Invoice_Id, Product_id, Quantity, Price.

The InvoiceLine table will have one row per product that was purchased on this invoice. It will have a unique InvoiceLine_Id per row (key field), and the InvoiceId field in it can be repeated across rows because it will be a many-to-one foreign key relationship to the InvoiceHeader table.

Comment: Thats great, thank you. I can see that working

Comment: No problem! That's a typical schema for a system that deals with Orders. Generally you'll see the Sales table be broken out in a similar way, SalesHeader and SalesLine where the header will have the parent information about the sale (Sales_Id, SalesDate, Customer_Id, TotalCost) and the lines would be one line per Product sold with fields representing Quantity, ItemPrice etc. :)